# How does line-height vertically center text?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to understand why the `line-height` CSS property places the text vertically in the middle of this button:

```css
.btn-order {
    width: 220px;
    height: 58px;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 58px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-order">Complete Order</div>
```

Comment: @BoltClock `line-height` is a rule for appearance editing, not necessarily for vertically aligning within a button. He is asking why this technique of centering text inside a button works.

Comment: Depending on what I'm doing, I sometimes use padding: http://jsfiddle.net/YawDF/19/ - Dunno if it's fitting in your case given that you have width and height set, but for future reference.

Comment: "why we must put line-height in this case?" - Well, you *don't* need it: http://jsfiddle.net/YawDF/20/. In fact, your CSS is very rigid, you rarely need to set absolute width and height like that.

Answer (score 19):

The `line-height` property is essentially setting a `29px` *(29 + 29 = 58)* text line above and below your text, "Complete Order". If you added another line of text below this you will find it `58px` below this text. You are putting line-height here only to center your text in the middle.

Here is a good slide show to help you understand this concept more... [line-height](http://www.slideshare.net/maxdesign/line-height)

And here is an example using your code of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/YawDF/14/

By setting the `line-height` to `58px` you are telling the browser to leave half this above and below the text line, creating a '58px' gap between each line and only a '29px' gap above the first line.

*SIDE NOTE: Your use of `vertical-align: middle` is useless in the code you are showing. This can be taken out all together.*

Comment: It's not true that vertical-align:middle is only for tables. Here is a simple demo of vertical-align working without tables: http://jsfiddle.net/YZUTM/

Comment: @Alohci No, Michael meant that the vertical-align in the OP's fiddle was useless, because it wouldn't do anything in that case. vertical-align works very different in table cells than it does everywhere else. Michael's wording is not very clear though...

Comment: @MrLister - Indeed. The sentence is at best misleading. It needs some sort of clarification.

Comment: @Alohci if you look at your updated fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/YZUTM/7/, you will see your middle no longer works. The only reason it was working before was because you had a `line-height` set to your parent element, as well as `text-align: center`. Please show me an instance where `vertical-align: middle;` works without working with tables. Thanks.

Comment: @Alohci correction... NONE of your alignments work without the added CSS you used. Take out the vertical alignment and you get the same affect. http://jsfiddle.net/YZUTM/15/

Comment: @MichaelRader - I don't understand. I know my example only works when using a line-height on the parent element. But using a line-height is not the same as using a table.

Comment: @Alohci why are you using a `text-align: center;`. This defeats the whole purpose of trying to see if `vertical-align` is working for you.

Comment: `text-align: center;` is just a left-over from the original jsfiddle. It's of no consequence one way or other. Here's a JSFiddle without it. http://jsfiddle.net/YZUTM/18/

Comment: @Alohci and that jsfiddle your showing me still does not reflect `verticle-align: middle`

Comment: Which browser are you looking at it with?

Comment: @Alohci any browser will not reflect the "center" being centered in the midel of the box using `verticle-align: middle;`

Comment: @Alohci The `vertical-align` has nothing to do with why the text is centered, don't you see that? Just remove that code and you still have the same affect. http://jsfiddle.net/YZUTM/20/

Comment: I did. The text moved. It no longer lined up with the table vertical-aligned one on the right. Tried Firefox and Chrome. Therefore vertical-align:middle is doing *something*.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a paragraph is inserted in a division the distance between the first line and the top border of the div is half of the line-height i.e if the default line- height is 1px then the distance between the first line and the top-border of the div is 0.5px.

If you have a division with `height:58px` the  distance between the line and the top-border of the div is 29px and the distance between the line and the border of the bottom div would be=(total div height-distance b/w the line and the top border) which is 58px-29px=29px.This results in the line being vertically aligned at the center.

Also,there is no need to use `vertical align:middle`(for text containing not more than one line) if you're using line-height to centrally align the text.

Answer (score 0):

it is by design. If the CSS parser (i.e. the browser) doesn't know how tall is your text, he can't vertical align your text correctly.

Note there is a default value of `line-height` property.

Answer (score 0):

line-height defines the height of text which make the paragraph looks neat so vertical-align works with respect to line-height when you increase the line height it increases the height and the you can more clearly see the effects of vertical-alignment of text

think this as a notebook which we children use to learn English -writing in nursery class

Comment: It does not. It defines the height of the inline box the text resides in, not the height of the text itself.

Comment: sorry for my bad english but i too mean this

Answer (score 0):

[The text you generate is inside its own line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-boxes) and vertical-align is used for placement inside that box. However, that box has nothing to do with the div you have wrapped around the text. You set the height of the div to 58px but that does not affect the height of the line text box. That is why you need line-height to match the height of the div.

Comment: "...placement inside **that** box". Not quite. vertical-align is used for placement of inline boxes within the **line boxes** that each inline box spans. Strictly, [CSS 2.1 says](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) "On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

Comment: @Alohci - You are mis-reading that. What you quote is for line boxes inside a block level element. I'm strictly speaking about the line boxes themselves.

Comment: Your answer talks of **inline boxes** not **line boxes**. Your comment talks of line boxes. They're very different things. You need to be clearer which you are referring to.