# This div height is always smaller than the parent div

Tags: css, height, html-lists, separator

So I've tried quite a few attempts while looking at some answers here, but I can't seem to align the text fully in the parent div and to make the white separators be the full length of the parent div.

https://jsfiddle.net/oxgg6qrf/ <-- This is my attempt, but I'm not sure what is forcing the separator div to be smaller.

Code is below:

```
<div id="ambMenu">
    <ul id="ulMenu">
        <li id="liMenuBar1"><div class="ambMenuDivider"></div></li>
        <li id="liMenuOption1">Test1</li>
        <li id="liMenuBar2"><div class="ambMenuDivider"></div></li>
        <li id="liMenuOption2">Test2</li>
        <li id="liMenuBar3"><div class="ambMenuDivider"></div></li>
        <li id="liMenuOption3">Test3</li>
        <li id="liMenuBar4"><div class="ambMenuDivider"></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#ambMenu { width: 360px; height: 25px; background-color: #333; color: #f2f2f2; }
#ulMenu { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; display: inline-block; }
#liMenuBar1 { padding-left: 30px; float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 0; }
#liMenuBar2, #liMenuBar3, #liMenuBar4 { float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 0; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 5px; }
#liMenuOption1, #liMenuOption2, #liMenuOption3 { float: left; display: inline-block; margin: 0; vertical-align: middle; }
.ambMenuDivider { border-left:5px solid #f2f2f2; display: inline; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px;}
```

I know there's a lot of ids, but I need them later for a js script.

Is there a better way to create a menu of this sort with this aspect? Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary container has a specified height of 25px:

```
#ambMenu { 
    width: 360px; 
    height: 25px; /* height of container */
    background-color: #333; 
    color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

But your child container has no height specified. So, first step, give the child container the same height as the parent container:

```
#ulMenu {
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    height: 25px; /* new */
}
```

In order [to vertically center the text apply a `line-height`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8799164/3597276) to the list items equal to the height of container:

```
#liMenuBar1 { 
    padding-left: 30px; 
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 25px; /* new */
}

#liMenuBar2, #liMenuBar3, #liMenuBar4 { 
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding-left: 10px; 
    padding-right: 5px;
    line-height: 25px; /* new */
}

#liMenuOption1, #liMenuOption2, #liMenuOption3 {
    float: left; 
    display: block; 
    margin: 0; 
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px; /* new */
}

.ambMenuDivider { 
    border-left:5px solid #f2f2f2; 
    display: inline; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-right: 5px;
    line-height: 25px; /* new */
}
```

Now the text is vertically centered in the container.

To get the menu dividers to stretch the entire height, you need to make two adjustments:

1. Apply `height: 25px`
2. Change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` <sup>*</sup>

   ```
   .ambMenuDivider { 
       border-left:5px solid #f2f2f2; 
       display: inline-block; /* adjusted */
       padding-left: 5px; 
       padding-right: 5px;
       line-height: 25px; /* new */
       height: 25px; /* new */
   }
   ```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/oxgg6qrf/2/

<sup>*</sup> *[You cannot apply `height` to inline elements.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced).*

Comment: Oooh, so I was just missing line-height when compared to all the tries I did ! I tried applying height to that div but nothing changed since I didn't have it I guess (plus I was using height in li and so to try and get the div to work). Thanks this is what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/ddma2hLy/)

Main change was adding `height: 25px;` after removing some css classes.

It can be better but its what you want right now.
I removed the classes which is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are another way to solve the issue. Please replace the following ID's.

```
#ulMenu {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 14px;
    }

#ulMenu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use a right-hand border on each menu item, plus a left-hand border on the first item.

Then you don't need separate div elements for menu dividers. This simplifies everything.

HTML:

```
<div id="ambMenu">
    <ul id="ulMenu">
        <li id="liMenuOption1">Test1</li>
        <li id="liMenuOption2">Test2</li>
        <li id="liMenuOption3">Test3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#ambMenu {
    width:360px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:#333;
    color:#f2f2f2;
}

#ulMenu {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#ulMenu li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 25px;  /* Height of list items */
    padding: 0px 10px;  /* Space around items (0px vertical, 10px horizontal) */
    border-right: 5px solid #f2f2f2;  /* Vertical separators after each item */
}

/* Special rules for the first list item. */

#ulMenu li:first-child {
    margin-left: 30px;  /* Add space to the left */
    border-left: 5px solid #f2f2f2;  /* Vertical separator before first item */
}
```

Comment: I didn't see this reply at first, but I ended up following your suggestion since it was cleaner. Thanks!